# 3-dim putty (ssh)

Tags: html, opengl, 3d, jogl

Imagine a 3-dim putty - a polyhedron which every facet is a putty shell.

A few Qs:
1. Is there already such a thing?
2. How can I easily implement a cube/polyhedron that rotates freely, so that on each facet - I can decide what to show (for example, a putty shell). I really don't want to dwell on the graphics part, unless I have to. So any easily prepared graphic would be nice, as long as it supports my requirement. Can openGL help me? JOGL? HTML5? (I don't mind it being in a browser)

Comment: This question really needs a but more information/code that shows what is going on. What the hell is a putty shell? I'm not sure whether you mean the Windows SSH client, or a soft squidgy material? OpenGL makes me think the latter, but then you say HTML5 which makes me think you have no idea what you are talking about :)

Comment: You want a d20 made of putty with ssh sessions instead of numbers, in a browser, in 3d? For like, super spinning 3d ninja sysadminning? Voting for most ridiculous (semi-legitimate) question of the day.

Comment: relax, guys. Yes, I meant an SSH client (as seen in the headline) - I want to know which technology can help me create a 3D shape that each facet is like a command line. I don't think it is illegitimate. I referred to HTML5's canvas abilities which support 3D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really weird question, not even sure it belongs here, but seems fun anyway...

Have a look here : http://www.jukie.net/bart/blog/popenRWE

So I'd say : start a bash instance with this variant of popen which handles both writes and reads, use the pipes for input and output, forward keyboard strokes to input, and render the output in OpenGL, probably in a rendertexture.

Repeat for each side...

Not html5 or jogl, though. Plain old C or C++.

Comment: Thnanks. What I an mostly looking for - is the how. Let's say I drew the cube on openGL. Let's say I can sililiate an interactive shall - how do I had writing to the cube and make it respond to keyboard events.

Comment: It's in the anwser already... forward keyboard strokes to the input pipe, and render the text from the output pipe in OpenGL...

Comment: How do I go about writing text on facets?

Comment: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-11-2d-text/ , but really this is not the big problem.

Answer (score 1):

Compiz's [Desktop Cube](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Cube) and six fullscreen Xterms.